# Magento 2.1.3 Role Resource Tree Not Showing

Tags: magento-2.1.3, role

I have a clean install of **Magento 2.1.3** with sample data. No themes or plugins have been added.

**When I create a new role, the role resource tree does not display**, and there is no other error or warning on the page.

There are some posts related to earlier Magento releases that speak about the `acl.xml` file requiring change - and yet others claiming to have fixed the issue by changing folder permissions **(no folders were listed, nor were we shown which permissions needed to be changed).**

If I have to go through the entire Magento documentation I will, but the point of coming to any forum is to share information and hopefully save time.

Should I come across the solution, I will come back and post the answer. If anyone has already tackled this, a detailed response would be appreciated.

Disclaimer: I am very new to **Magento 2.1x** - the most recent Magento experience I had was **CE 1.7**.

**Thank you in advance to all!**

Comment: did you solve it , i am facing same issue ,
resource tree is not showing ,
when i developer mode no error is shown

Answer (score 1):

path : /vendor/magento/module-user/Block/Role/Tab/Edit.php

```
 in the function getTree() I changed:
isset($resources[1]['children']) ? $resources[1]['children']
into:
isset($resources[2]['children']) ? $resources[2]['children']
and the resource tree is shown again.
```

[For More Details](https://www.oolalaji.com/blog/post/why-magento-2-1-x-roles-resource-tree-not-showing.html)

Answer (score -1):

Since this question was posted, our company signed up with Magento EE (Enterprise Edition), which includes lots of tech support. The Magento help team told me that it was in fact a permissions issue with the acl file, but instead of telling me where to fix it, they insisted on logging in and fixing it themselves.

Personally, I prefer to teach someone how to fish rather than just giving them a fish. Next time this occurs, the only answer we've got is to contact Magento support for a fix. Hardly a fix. I wish I could provide a better answer, save to say, that some research on the acl.xml might be helpful.

Good luck to all.